# What's the difference between returning void vs returning Future<void>?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, async-await, future, dart-async

Is there a difference between an `async` method that returns `void`, and one that returns `Future<void>`? It seems that both are valid in Dart:

```
void main() async {
    await myVoid();
    await myFutureVoid();
}


void myVoid() async {
    // Do something
}


Future<void> myFutureVoid() async {
    // Do something
}
```

Are they identical?

If so, why is `void` allowed when for example `int` is not? The compiler says *"Functions marked 'async' must have a return type assignable to 'Future'"*.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`void f()` and `Future<void> f()` are not identical. (The presence of the `async` keyword doesn't actually matter.  The `async` keyword primarily enables the use of the `await` keyword in the function body.)

`void f()` declares a function that returns nothing.  If it does asynchronous work, then that work will be "fire-and-forget": there is no opportunity for the caller of `f` to wait for it to finish.

In contrast, `Future<void> f()` declares a function that returns a `Future` that the caller can wait for (either by using `await` or by registering a `Future.then()` callback).  There's no value returned by the asynchronous work, but callers can determine when it is finished.

Functions marked with `async` *usually* should return a `Future`.  If you have a function that does asynchronous work that produces an actual value (such as an `int`), then the caller *must* wait for that value to be computed before it can be used.  That function therefore must return a `Future`.

As a special case, an `async` function can return `void` instead of `Future<void>` to indicate that it is fire-and-forget.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. Just to be clear - if `myVoid` uses `await` for all it's async calls (i.e. it basically becomes a sync method), then it _is_ possible for `main` to wait for `myVoid` to finish... right? I think that's what got me confused, since I encountered such a function and couldn't figure out why it was returning `void` instead of `Future<void>`. Especially what confused me was that IntelliJ hints _"Await only futures."_ - but it is still possible to await the function even though it returns `void`, just the same as if changing it to `Future<void>`...

Comment: While it's true that `await myVoid();` is legal, it's not the same as `await myFutureVoid();`.  A caller would not be able to wait for `myVoid` to finish.  There is a special case where the Dart VM/runtime recognizes that there are outstanding `Future`s and won't exit until they complete, and that might make it *seem* like `main` is waiting.  However, if you did `await myVoid(); print('foo');`, you would see `foo` printed before `myVoid` completes it async work.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if I understand you correctly - if i did `await myVoid(); print('foo');` and `myVoid` is doing `await` on all its async operations, wouldn't `foo` be printed _after_ `myVoid` returns? That's the case I meant in my previous comment. I made a Gist/Dartpad sample to illustrate what I mean: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b1acdb31305a1568cf33dc56e8df763f

Comment: Huh.  I stand corrected about current behavior.  It's *supposed* to be an error (but isn't yet for backward compatibility reasons).  You should avoid `await`ing `void`; it might break in the future (pun not intended).  Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28305 and https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33415