# Future<void> async vs simply void async in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, future

In Dart,

what is the difference between saying

```
Future<void> doStuff() async { ...
```

and

```
void doStuff() async { ...
```

I know what a Future<T> is and how async/await work generally, but I never realized Future<void> was a thing.  I have some code that has the Future<void> all over the place and I want to replace it with my normal way of doing things, but I don't want to break anything.

Notice that both functions use async.  The question is NOT 'what is the difference between async and non-async functions?' or 'can you give a brief attempt at explaining asynchronous programming in Dart, please?'

I'm aware that there is a pretty much identical question already, but if you look closely at the answers you will see nobody actually answered the question in a clear way -- what is the difference?  Is there any difference?  Is there no difference?

To elaborate, consider the following two functions:

```
// notice there is no warning about not returning anything
Future<void> futureVoid() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      var time = DateTime.now().toString();
      print('$time : delay elapsed');
    });
}

void nonFutureVoid() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      var time = DateTime.now().toString();
      print('$time : delay elapsed');
    });
}
```

Then test them with a button whose onPressed() function is:

```
onPressed: () async {
    await nonFutureVoid(); // notce that this await *DOES* delay execution of the proceeding lines.
    var time = DateTime.now().toString();
    print('$time : <-- executed after await statement');
}
```

Log result:

```
flutter: 2021-02-23 21:46:07.436496 : delay elapsed
flutter: 2021-02-23 21:46:07.437278 : <-- executed after await statement
```

As you can see, they both behave exactly the same way -- the simple void async version IS awaited.  So what is the difference?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an identical question that I did actually answer: [What's the difference between returning void vs returning Future<void>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56244025/whats-the-difference-between-returning-void-vs-returning-futurevoid)

Comment: Well I didn't know that question was there, thx... it's not the greatest though as the actual difference is hashed out in comments and seems inconclusive.

Comment: You cant await the void, you can await the Future<void> that's the difference.

Comment: @NerdyBunz Huh? The difference is explained in the answer: callers cannot wait for an asynchronous `void` function to complete.  Period.  There's nothing inconclusive about that.

Comment: I predict that comment will be deleted. :D

Comment: I don't know what more you want, I answered it. They are both async, one can be awaited, the other can not. That's the difference. The fact you could `await void` previously was a bug, and has been fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With your edit, your question makes more sense.  Your question is really about principle vs. practice.

In principle, a function that returns `void` is different from a function that returns `Future<void>`.  One *conceptually* represents something that does not return anything, and the other represents an asynchronous computation that can fire callbacks when it completes.

In principle, you should *never* attempt to use the value returned from a `void` function.  It doesn't make sense.  If you run the Dart analyzer against code that does `await nonFutureVoid();` you'll get a warning if the [`await_only_futures` lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/await_only_futures.html) is enabled.

In practice, there *are* cases where attempting to use a `void` return value happens to not generate an error. Those are quirks in the language (or bugs in the implementation); **you should not rely on them**. (Dart didn't originally have a `void` return type. When it was added later, it wasn't implemented to mean "no value" but instead to mean "a value that you aren't allowed to use".  See [Dart 2: Legacy of the `void`](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-legacy-of-the-void-e7afb5f44df0).  Normally that subtle difference shouldn't matter.)

Being able to do `await nonFutureVoid();` is a [bug](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/932)<sup>1</sup>, and it seems that **that bug is now fixed**: `await nonFutureVoid();` is an error if you use Dart 2.12 or later and enable null-safety and the stricter type-checking that comes with it.

You can observe the old and new behaviors with DartPad by toggling the "Null Safety" button: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b0dae0d5a50e302d26d93f2db3fa6207

---

<sup>1</sup> There are a lot of issues filed on GitHub with a lot of back-and-forth discussion, so yes, it is rather confusing.  Most people seemed to agree that allowing `await void` was undesirable, however.

Answer (score 3):

A `void` function indicates that the function returns nothing, which means you can not act on the result of that Function (and cannot `await` on it's result).

Meanwhile, the `Future<void>` function returns a Future object (that has value of `void`). If you don't have a `return` statement, a `missing_return` warning will show up (it can still be compiled). You can still act on that result by awaiting it, but cannot actually use the value because it's `void`.

While it seems like it'd be just fine with whatever you are using, I think it's better to use `Future` for every `async` function for type-safety and better maintenance.

Comment: Future<void> does not requre a return statement AFAIK. The difference is just that one can be awaited and the other can not I think? I actually didn't realize that would compile...

Comment: @shawnblais Yeah currently it's not required, only a warning. You're right as well, the `void` function cannot be awaited since it indicates it's not gonna return anything