# FutureOr can await void functions?

Tags: dart, async-await, future

As far as I understand it should not be possible to await functions like `void foo() async {}`, because they return no future that could be awaited. But I noticed when I assign them to a `FutureOr<void> Function()` field it is possible to await them. The following example prints: PRE, FUNC, POST

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void func() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  
  print('FUNC');
}

Future<void> main() async {
  final FutureOr<void> Function() t = func;
  
  print('PRE');
  await t();
  print('POST');
}
```

I would expect it to print: PRE, POST, FUNC

Because the function `func` cannot be await (because it returns void) and therefore the `await t()` should not wait for the completion of the `func` function.

I observed the same behavior with `final dynamic Function() t = func;`

I'm not sure if this behavior is intended or if I just don't understand void async functions?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66381710/ for some background. `void Function()` is a subtype of `FutureOr<void> Function()`, so the former is substitutable for the latter. `await` on a `FutureOr<void>` also is okay.  That the `await` successfully waits for the asynchronous operations in the `void` function to complete is an artifact of how `void` works in Dart (it's a promise not to use the value).  You probably should consider this to be a bug and not rely on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `await` operator can be used on any *object* and on an expression of any type except `void` (and that's only because the type `void` is specifically disallowed in most contexts, not something special for `await`).

An `async` function always returns a future. Even if its declared return type is `void`. Declaring the return type as void is just a signal to users that they shouldn't expect a useful value, and it makes it harder to actually get to the value (because of the above-mentioned restrictions on using `void` typed expressions).

In fact, all `void` return-type functions return a value (unless they throw). That value is *usually* `null`, but it's not required to be.
Since you can *override* a `void foo()` method with `int foo()` in a subclass, and assign an `int Function()` to a variable of type `void Function()`, the compiler can't actually know for sure that a function with static type `void` does not return anything. So, it doesn't even try to enforce it for functions that are themselves typed as returning `void`.

The type `FutureOr<void>` is a supertype of `void` (and of `Future<void>`), so a `void Function()` function object is assignable to the type `FutureOr<void> Function()`.

All in all, that conspires to allow your code to work the way you see.
The `await t()` performs an `await` on an expression with static type `FutureOr<void>` and an actual value which is a `Future<void>`, which was returned by a call to `func`. So, the `await t()` waits for `FUNC` to be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `await` if you want skip task. Use `Future.sync()` or `Future.microtask()` in you case. [Documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-async/Future-class.html)

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void func() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  
  print('FUNC');
}

Future<void> main() async {
  final FutureOr<void> Function() t = func;
  
  print('PRE');
  Future.microtask(t);
  print('POST');
}
```

By using `await` you telling to compilator that you want to wait until some task will be completed and no mater it's `void` or not.