# Flutter Future<void> vs Future<Null> vs void

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the main difference between:

1. `Future<void> function(){}`
2. `Future<Null> function(){}`
3. `void function() {}`
4. `funtion(){}`

Sometimes I use void or future when calling the API but I don't really know what the main difference is and when is the right time to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. By default, a function likes `function() {}` returns a `null` pointer value.
   Use this archetype when your function not return anything and it's not marked as `async`:

```dart
function() { // <- not async
 // ... some code
 // ... don't use return
}
```

2. Optionally, you can specify not return values using `void function() {}` sintaxis. It's same at the `function() {}` but if you try to assign a value after calling you will get an error in compile time:

`Error: This expression has type 'void' and can't be used.`

Personally, i recommend this approach if you really don't have a return value and the function it's not async.
Note that you can use `void` in normal and async functions.

3. A function likes `Future<void> function() async {}` is for asynchronous function thats returns a `Future<void>` object.

I personally recommend the `void function() async {}` only if you don't use `await` ot `then` on call your function, otherwise, use `Future <void> function() async {}`.

An examples:

```dart
Future<void> myFunction() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  print('Hello');
}

void main() async {
  print(myFunction()); // This works and prints 
                     // Instance of '_Future<void>'
                     // Hello
  // Use this approach if you use this:
  myFunction().then(() {
    print('Then myFunction call ended');
  })

  // or this
  await myFunction();
  print('Then myFunction call ended');
}
```

```dart
void myFunction() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  print('Hello');
}

void main() async {
  print(myFunction()); // This not works
                     // The compile fails and show
                     // Error: This expression has type 'void' and can't be used.
  // In this case you only can call myFunction like this
  myFunction();

  // This doesn't works (Compilation Error)
  myFunction().then(() {
    print('Then myFunction call ended');
  });

  // This doesn't works (Compilation Error)
  await myFunction();
  print('Then myFunction call ended');
}
```

4. A function likes `Future<Null> function() async {}` returns a `Future<null>` object. Use it whenever you return `null`. It's not recommended to use it because class `Null` not extends from `Object` and anything you return marks an error (except statements thats returns a null or explicit null value):

```dart
Future<Null> myFunction() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  print('Hello');

  // Ok
  return (() => null)();
  
  // Ok
  return null;
}
```

Comment: thank you, the explanation is very helpful and easy to understand

Answer (score 15):

1. `Future<void> function() {}`

   Defines an asynchronous function that ultimately returns nothing but can notify callers when it eventually completes.  Also see: [What's the difference between returning void vs returning Future?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56244025/)
2. `Future<Null> function() {}`

   Defines an asynchronous function that ultimately returns `null` when it eventually completes.  Don't use this; this is an archaic form of `Future<void>`.  It predates Dart 2 and was necessary because `void` was not yet a proper type, and there was no mechanism for indicating that a `Future` should return nothing.  Also see: [Dart 2: Legacy of the `void`](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-legacy-of-the-void-e7afb5f44df0)
3. `void function() {}`

   Defines a function that returns nothing.  If the function does asynchronous work, callers will not be able to directly tell when it is complete.
4. `function() {}`

   Defines a function with an unspecified return type.  The return type is implicitly `dynamic`, which means that the function can return anything. Don't do this since it does not convey intent; readers will not be able to tell if the return type was omitted intentionally or accidentally.  It also will trigger the [`always_declare_return_types` lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/always_declare_return_types.html).  If you actually want to return a `dynamic` type, you should explicitly use `dynamic function() {}` instead.