# What the consequence does await introduce the program in dart?

Tags: dart, async-await, future

Why is the follow code valid? I thought there should be compile-time errors. I thought the `return` in the body return an `int`(value `1`). If not, it must be returning a `Future`, which does not comply to the return type either. What has happened with the `await`?

```dart
void longRun() async {
 return await Future.delayed(
   Duration(seconds: 3),
   ()=>1,
 );
}
```

If I assign the `await` part to a variable, like the following, the compiler starts to complain, which is obvious and easy to understand. But why doesn't the code above complain?

```dart
void longRun() async {
  var foo = await Future.delayed(
    Duration(seconds: 3),
    ()=>1,
  );
  return foo;
}
```

Keep studying I've found more confusing thing: all the following versions work. They seem identical, wired.

version1:

```
void longRun() async {
   return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2), ()=>1);
}
```

version2:

```
Future<void> longRun() async {
   return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2), ()=>1);
}
```

version3:

```
Future<int> longRun() async {
   return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2), ()=>1);
}
```

version4:

```
Future longRun() async {
   return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2), ()=>1);
}
```

version5:

```
Future longRun() async {
   await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2), ()=>1);
}
```

version6:

```
void longRun() async {
   await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2), ()=>1);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is mostly about the behavior of `=>`, not about `await`.  Normally `() => 1` can be thought of as shorthand for `() { return 1; }`, but that's actually an oversimplification.

`=>` is allowed for `void` functions as a convenience so that people can write things like:

```dart
bool functionWithSideEffect() {
  print('Some side effect');
  return true;
}

void foo() => functionWithSideEffect();

int _someValue = 0;
set someValue(int value) => _someValue = value;
```

even though these aren't legal:

```dart
var foo() {
  // error: A value of type 'bool' can't be returned  from the function 'foo' 
  // because it has a return type of 'void'.
  return functionWithSideEffect();
}

set someValue(int value) {
  // error: A value of type 'int' can't be returned  from the function
  // 'someValue' because it has a return type of 'void'.
  return _someValue = value;
}
```

The crux of your confusion is that `() => 1` either could be `int Function()` or `void Function()`, and type inference picks different things given different constraints.

When you do:

> ```dart
> void longRun() async {
>  return await Future.delayed(
>    Duration(seconds: 3),
>    ()=>1,
>  );
> }
> ```

then type inference works outside-in, propagating the `void` return type of `longRun` through the unconstrained, returned expression.  The `Future.delayed` call is inferred to be `Future<void>.delayed` and the `() => 1` callback is inferred to be `void Function()`. (Arguably a `void` `async` function returning `Future<void>` could be treated as error.)

In contrast, when you do:

> ```dart
> void longRun() async {
>   var foo = await Future.delayed(
>     Duration(seconds: 3),
>     ()=>1,
>   );
>   return foo;
> }
> ```

now type inference runs in the *other* direction (inside-out): `foo` has no explicit type, so it does not constrain the right-hand-side. Therefore `() => 1` is instead assumed to be `int Function()`, which causes `Future.delayed` to be inferred to be `Future<int>.delayed` and `foo` to be inferred as an `int`.  Since `foo` is an `int`, attempting to return it from a function declared to return `void` is an error.

> version2:
>
> ```dart
> Future<void> longRun() async {
>    return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2), ()=>1);
> }
> ```

You've changed `longRun`'s return type from `void` to `Future<void>`. [`async` functions usually should return a `Future` but may also return `void` to be fire-and-forget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56249235/).  The only difference from version 1 is that callers can now wait (fire a callback) when `longRun` completes. `() => 1` is still inferred to be `void Function()`.

> version3:
>
> ```dart
> Future<int> longRun() async {
>    return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2), ()=>1);
> }
> ```

Same as version2 except `longRun` returns `Future<int>` instead of `Future<void>`.  Now `() => 1` is inferred to be `int Function()`.

> version4:
>
> ```dart
> Future longRun() async {
>    return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2), ()=>1);
> }
> ```

`longRun`'s return type is now `Future`, which means `Future<dynamic>`. `() => 1` is inferred to be `dynamic Function()`.

> version5:
>
> ```dart
> Future longRun() async {
>    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2), ()=>1);
> }
> ```

Same as version4 except there is no explicit `return` statement.  Now the `Future.delayed` expression is no longer constrained by `longRun`'s return type, and inference will flow inside-out; `() => 1` is assumed to be `int Function()`.

> version6:
>
> ```dart
> void longRun() async {
>    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2), ()=>1);
> }
> ```

Same as version5 except that `longRun` returns `void` and is a fire-and-forget function.  Callers cannot be notified when `longRun` completes.

(Note that in the above, when I write `() => 1` is inferred to be `int Function()` or `void Function()`, it really should be `FutureOr<int> Function()` or `FutureOr<void> Function()`, but that's not the important part.)

---

Edit:

Pre-emptively addressing some potential follow-up questions:

Why is:

```dart
void longRun() async {
  int f() {
    return 1;
  }

  return await Future<void>.delayed(
    Duration(seconds: 3),
    f,
  );
}
```

okay, but:

```dart
void longRun() async {
  return await Future<void>.delayed(
    Duration(seconds: 3),
    // info: Don't assign to void. 
    () {
      return 1;
    },
  );
}
```

generates an analysis complaint?  Both versions are legal because substituting a `Future<U>` for a `Future<T>` is legal when `U` is a subtype of `T`.  When `T` is `void`, `U` can be anything; the value can just be ignored. (In Dart, partly for historical reasons when it didn't always have a `void` type, `void` actually means that the value cannot be used and not that there is no value. `void x = 42;` is legal, but attempting to read the value of `x` would be an error.  This is why the "Don't assign to void" analysis complaint isn't categorized as an error.)

In the second version that uses an anonymous function, the tighter locality of the `return` statement allows the analyzer to perform more extensive checks.