# How to wait for action of user in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with a function. I need to realize a func which will be work correctly when user taps on button. I need to froze this func and wait for user's action. (tap on button).
Maybe y have already to faced to the same prob

```
  void submitAnswer(String submittedAnswer) async {
    timerAnimationController.stop();
    if (!context.read<QuestionsCubit>().questions()[currentQuestionIndex].attempted) {
      context.read<QuestionsCubit>().updateQuestionWithAnswerAndLifeline(context.read<QuestionsCubit>().questions()[currentQuestionIndex].id, submittedAnswer);
      updateTotalSecondsToCompleteQuiz();
      //change question
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: inBetweenQuestionTimeInSeconds));
      if (currentQuestionIndex != (context.read<QuestionsCubit>().questions().length - 1)) {
        updateSubmittedAnswerForBookmark(context.read<QuestionsCubit>().questions()[currentQuestionIndex]);
        timerAnimationController.stop();

        //I want to froze this part and wait for user's action.
        //When user taps on 'next', it continues working.
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        changeQuestion();
        if (widget.quizType == QuizTypes.audioQuestions) {
          timerAnimationController.value = 0.0;
          showOptionAnimationController.forward();
        } else {
          timerAnimationController.forward(from: 0.0);
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      } else {
        updateSubmittedAnswerForBookmark(context.read<QuestionsCubit>().questions()[currentQuestionIndex]);
        navigateToResultScreen();
      }
    }
  }
```

When user taps on button, this func continue working

```
TextButton(
        child: Text("Next >>"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              callMyFun();
            });
            //global.setMyStatus == true;
          }
      )
```

Comment: Also, I've noticed that you are using `void` instead of `Future<void>`, so this may be useful knowledge for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56244025

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Disclaimer: while this will solve your problem, it's far away from
> good practice, you should split your function into two
> different ones

You can achieve that using [Completer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Completer-class.html)

Example:

```
Completer<void>? nextButtonCompleter;

Future<void> submitAnswer(String submittedAnswer) async {
  // Your code (removed to make answer short)
  // ...
  //I want to froze this part and wait for user's action.
  //When user taps on 'next', it continues working.

  final completer = new Completer<void>();
  nextButtonCompleter = completer;
  // This line will wait until onPressed called
  await completer.future; 
  
  // your other code
}
```

And in your button

```
TextButton(
  child: Text("Next >>"),
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      callMyFun();
    });
    nextButtonCompleter?.complete();
    nextButtonCompleter = null;
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you!
Bur it doesn't work. My func continue working anyway

Comment: @SaturnPro maybe you put my lines in the wrong place? Please make a gist, I will take a look

Comment: @ Dima Rostopira
Sory, i was wrong. Your method is helped me, Thank you! =)