# Using async value in another function (Dart)

Tags: dart

Here's the simplifed code to show what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class MyClass {
  MyClass() {
    authorize();
  }

  String? token;

  void authorize() async {
    final response =
        await Future<String>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), (() => "14dw65d1q"));
    token = response;
    print('Token: $token');
  }

  String printToken() {
    return 'Token: $token';
  }
}

void main() {
  final myClass = MyClass();
  print(myClass.printToken());
}
```

Basically I'm trying to use `token` (whose default value of `null` is changed by `authorize()`) in another function. The output is:

```
Token: null
Token: 14dw65d1q
```

Apparently, `main()` runs before the value of token gets assigned. Thus, I get a 401 error when I try to use `token` in the header of a network request. (Not shown in code) How can I make `printToken()` run **after** the value of `token` gets assigned? Making `main()` async and/or awaiting `myClass.printToken()` doesn't work. I get `'await' applied to 'String', which is not a 'Future'.` when I await `'Token: $token'` or `myClass.printToken()` anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MyClass` implementation does not provide any `Future`s to its consumers, and consumers therefore will not be able to be notified when asynchronous operations in `MyClass` complete.  There are two specific problems:

1. You've made the `authorize` method ["fire-and-forget" by returning `void`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56249235/).  That instead should return a `Future<void>` to allow callers to be notified when it completes.
2. You call `authorize` from within the `MyClass` constructor.  However, invoking a constructor must always result in an instance of the class, not a `Future`.

Possible fixes for problem #2:

- **Construct `MyClass` with a `static` method that returns a `Future`.**

  ```dart
  class MyClass {
    MyClass._();

    static Future<MyClass> createInstance() async {
      var instance = MyClass._();
      await instance.authorize();
      return instance;
    }

    String? token;

    Future<void> authorize() async {
      final response =
          await Future<String>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), (() => "14dw65d1q"));
      token = response;
      print('Token: $token');
    }

    String printToken() {
      return 'Token: $token';
    }
  }

  void main() async {
    final myClass = await MyClass.createInstance();
    print(myClass.printToken());
  }
  ```
- **Use a `Completer`.**

  ```dart
  import 'dart:async';

  class MyClass {
    MyClass() {
      authorize();
    }

    String? token;
    final _completer = Completer<void>();

    Future<void> get authorizationDone => _completer.future;

    Future<void> authorize() async {
      final response =
          await Future<String>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), (() => "14dw65d1q"));
      token = response;
      _completer.complete();
      print('Token: $token');
    }

    String printToken() {
      return 'Token: $token';
    }
  }

  void main() async {
    final myClass = MyClass();
    await myClass.authorizationDone;
    print(myClass.printToken());
  }
  ```
- **Move asynchronous operations out of the constructor.**

  ```dart
  class MyClass {
    MyClass();

    String? token;

    Future<void> authorize() async {
      final response =
          await Future<String>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), (() => "14dw65d1q"));
      token = response;
      print('Token: $token');
    }

    String printToken() {
      return 'Token: $token';
    }
  }

  void main() async {
    final myClass = MyClass();
    await myClass.authorize();
    print(myClass.printToken());
  }
  ```

I recommend using the first approach since it's less error-prone for callers and since [you usually shouldn't be using `Completer` directly](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-completer-directly).