# If my function calls an asynchronous function, does that force me to make my function return a Future?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, asynchronous

I'm learning about `async` and `await` in Dart. For the most part, it makes sense that it's a way to say that some function will take a while and that the program should run a particular function asynchronously.

What I'm not understanding is how that affects all the "preceding" functions that eventually lead to the given asynchronous function.

For example,

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<String> firstAsync() async {
  await Future<String>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  return "First!";
}

String secondAsync() async {
  var returnVal = await firstAsync();
  return returnVal;
}

void main() {
  var s = secondAsync();

  if (s == "First!") {
    ///run some code...
  }

  print('done');
}
```

1. `firstAsync` returns a future, so it makes sense that the function's return value is `Future<String>`. Then, `secondAsync` uses this function. Does that mean that `secondAsync` must also return `Future<String>`?
2. Does `main` need the `async` keyword and would I need to change its first line to `var s = await secondAsync();` ?
3. And if so, does that mean that `main` also needs to be marked as returning `Future<void>`?

Answer (score 2):

> If my function calls an asynchronous function, does that force me to make my function return a Future?

Not necessarily, but almost always.  If your function needs to return a result *that depends on the called asynchronous function*, then your function is implicitly asynchronous too and must return a `Future`.

If callers of your function don't need to be notified when your function completes, then your function is ["fire-and-forget" and can return `void` instead of a `Future`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56249235/).  Or if your function does not depend on the called asynchronous function (i.e., you're calling a fire-and-forget asynchronous function), then your function can return whatever it wants.  It's not waiting for anything.

> 1. `firstAsync` returns a future, so it makes sense that the function's return value is `Future<String>`. Then, `secondAsync` uses this function. Does that mean that `secondAsync` must also return `Future<String>`?

Yes.

> 2. Does `main` need the `async` keyword and would I need to change its first line to `var s = await secondAsync();` ?

Technically no (you could use the raw `Future` API directly and not use `await`), but you should prefer using `async`/`await`.  It's much easier to understand.

> 3. And if so, does that mean that `main` also needs to be marked as returning `Future<void>`?

Usually there is no caller of `main` that needs to wait for it complete (and the Dart VM/runtime will wait until the event queue is empty before exiting), so `main` usually can be considered fire-and-forget and can return `void`.  The current recommendation from the [`avoid_void_async` lint documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#avoid_void_async) is to not bother having `main` return a `Future`.

Having `main` return a `Future` *could* matter if you have a recursive `main` function or if your `.dart` file might be `import`ed by another file that directly invokes your `main()` function.  However, those circumstances would be very rare (and probably would be better off avoided anyway by refactoring).